# Aggregating watch-time in database query

Tags: database, postgresql

Using a schema like:

```
create table video (id primary key serial);

create table video_interaction (video_id int references video, time timestamptz not null);
```

I want to track watch time by aggregating chunks of interactions with a certain threshold interval

For example:

```
video_interaction
------------------
video_id, time
------------------
1, 00:01
1, 00:02

1, 00:06

1, 03:20 
1, 03:21
1, 03:22
1, 03:25 

1, 11:59
```

The result of `select video.id, video_interaction_time from video join ...` would be `(1, 00:10)` interaction-time (here the aggregation-interval is `00:03`).

Can this be done in a single query?

---

Essentially, is clustering like this possible in postgres?

Comment: Can you describe how you are getting 00:10?  Also, is 00:10 an interval or a timestamp?

Comment: @Jeremy its an interval. `sum(max(video_interaction_in_cluster) - min(video_interaction_in_cluster) + 1)`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand how you get 10 seconds from the data in your table.